# Building with maven errors - Spring security config

Tags: spring, maven, spring-security

When I'm trying to build my project with maven I am getting this error message.

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'authentication-manager'.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'global-method-security'.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'http'.
```

I am using Spring framework 3.0.2

Comment: What namespaces and xsds do you have in your security XML configuration?

Comment: @holmis83 spring-bean-3.0 and spring-security-3.0 xsds

Answer (score 0):

add

```
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd"
```

to your xml configuration